# Angular Reactive Forms - Dynamic Field Manipulation

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-forms

I'm working on an Angular application that uses reactive forms to create a dynamic form with the ability to add new fields and remove existing fields. However, I'm facing issues with some failing test cases, and I'm looking for help to fix them without changing the test cases themselves.

Problem Description:
I have implemented a dynamic form with the following requirements:

- Clicking the "Add new field" button should create and show a new
  field in the form.
- Each row of the form should consist of an input
  field and a "Remove field" button.
- Clicking the "Remove field" button
  should delete a field from the form.
- Each new field should be added
  to a control called "fields" within the main FormGroup.
- The displayed
  form should be updated when text is applied directly to the control.

The form component code is structured as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
      <button class="btn-add-new-row" (click)="handleAddNewField()">Add new field</button>
      <div formArrayName="fields">
        <fieldset *ngFor="let field of fields.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="text" formControlName="fieldName">
          <button class="btn-remove-field" (click)="handleRemoveField(i)">Remove field</button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </form>
  `  // put content here
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

get fields(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('fields') as FormArray;
  }

  handleAddNewField(): void {
   const newField = this.fb.group({ fieldName: '' });
    this.fields.push(newField);
  }

  handleRemoveField(index: number) {
    this.fields.removeAt(index);
  }

  private createForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      fields: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }
}
```

Test Cases:
I have two test cases that are failing:

**1. FormComponent API tests: Form value should be updated when new row was created**
Output (stderr):
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

```
- Expected  - 1
+ Received  + 3

  Object {
    "fields": Array [
-     "",
+     Object {
+       "fieldName": "",
+     },
    ],
  }
```

**2. FormComponent API tests: Form value should be updated when new value was put into input field**
Output (stderr):

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "custom message"
Received: {"fieldName": "custom message"}
```

I need help in fixing the code in such a way that these two test cases pass without modifying the test cases themselves. The code should initialize the fieldName with an empty string when adding a new field and should ensure that the form value matches the expected values in the test cases.

Is there a way to achieve this without altering the test cases?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.